# Geomedia Smart Client workflows exception in Action Index

Tags: geomedia

I'm trying to create a simple workflow and display it in the smart client java application

I followed the configuration steps here 
http://smartclient.intergraph.at/documentation/Workflow_Editor

and did the steps here
http://smartclient.intergraph.at/documentation/Creating_a_new_workflow_(How_To)

but at the last step i get an error, and the workflow doesn't show up in the java client

the error says "Could not find the specified connection MyNewWorkflow."
but i added the connection string and set the data source to my database

**Log**

```
06.11.2014 15:26:22 ERROR - Controller Workflow has raised an exception in Action Index.
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: Calling constructor Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowDatabase(Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IConnectionProvider connectionProvider).
Exception is: ConnectionNotFoundException - Could not find the specified connection MyNewWorkflow.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "workflowControllerContext" of constructor Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowController(Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IWorkflowControllerContext workflowControllerContext)
    Resolving Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.DatabaseWorkflowControllerContext,(none) (mapped from Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IWorkflowControllerContext, (none))
    Resolving parameter "database" of constructor Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.DatabaseWorkflowControllerContext(Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IRequestProvider requestProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IDescriptionProvider descriptionProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IWorkflowDatabase database, Intergraph.Emea.Security.ISessionProvider sessionProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IWorkflowNameProvider workflowNameProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IAuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.ISettingProvider settingProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Globalization.Localization localization, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IAssemblyResolver assemblyResolver, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IReportProvider reportProvider, Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IMapProvider mapProvider)
      Resolving Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowDatabase,(none) (mapped from Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IWorkflowDatabase, (none))
      Calling constructor Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowDatabase(Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)

   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
   at Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   --- Inner exception ---
Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.ConnectionNotFoundException: Could not find the specified connection MyNewWorkflow.
   at Intergraph.Emea.SmartClient.Workflows.SmartClientWorkflowConnectionProvider.GetConnectionSettings()
   at Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowDatabase..ctor(IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
   at BuildUp_Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowDatabase(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
   at BuildUp_Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.DatabaseWorkflowControllerContext(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey)
   at BuildUp_Intergraph.Emea.Workflows.WorkflowController(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)
```

Comment: Have you set up your workflow connection to MyNewWorkflow? "Could not find the specified connection MyNewWorkflow"

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps described here:
http://smartclient.intergraph.at/documentation/Integrated_Workflows_in_GeoMedia_Smart_Client

as Josh suggested, you probably missed the workflow connection in the administrator. 
Which type of license do you have? If you have just the runtime for the Workflow Manager you have to compile the workflow to get it to work:
http://smartclient.intergraph.at/documentation/Runtime_License_Administrator_(How_To)